# Error build ionic/cordova Android API 10

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

I found problems when compiling my project ionic/cordova (6) , looked in AndroidManifest.xml(platforms\android) and is setted correctly.

In AndroidManifest.xml(platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug) I attribute minsdk 10 but when I build the project it overwrites 14

I add on my config.xml preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" but not work....

I add on my manifest tools:overrideLibrary but not work...

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [android:CordovaLib:unspecified:debug] D:\XX\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\android\CordovaLib\unspecified\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
1>      Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage
1>
.....................
1>
1>  * Try:
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>MDAVSCLI : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning : ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem and even that with some fixes I could compile an apk, it didn't run properly on a device with Android api 10.

The reason is that according with the documentation if you are using Cordova version 6 you may not be able to build correct apk for Android API 10
You should use Cordova 4.0.X instead.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html